# Whether the input is a palidrome or not

Tags: python, python-3.x, palindrome

So, i am writing a code to check whether the entered string is a palindrome or not, i have written the following code, but its not working properly, for e.g, if i input "race" it still says TRUE, although it should say FALSE, Please help.
This is the code

```
string = input("Please enter any word: ")
a = 0
string_length = len(string)
for string_index in range(string_length-1, -1, -1):
    character = string[string_index]
    if string[a] == character:
        a = a + 1
        b = "TRUE"
    else:
        b = "FALSE"
print(b)
```

Comment: This [How to debug small programs (#1)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) might help your future self to debug your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct code:

```
a = 0
string_length = len(string)
for string_index in range(string_length-1, -1, -1):
    character = string[string_index]
    if string[a] == character:
        a = a + 1
        b = "TRUE"
    else:
        b = "FALSE"
        break;  # this line was missing
print(b)
```

Comment: just wrote this (a = a + 1), at the second last line, rather then the previous line, and it did the job for me, thanks though

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [this answer by מתן ל](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49841146/7505395):

You can easily compare your input agains itself when reversed - list comprehension makes this trivial:

**Simple 1-word and case-aware test:**

```
word = "SomemoS"
print(word == word[::-1])  # word[::-1] simply reverses the word and prints True if same
```

**Case insensitive and allow punctuation**

A palindrom is readable from both sides. Depending on the rules for palindrom-ness you might allow for ignored casing and even eleminate whitespaces and 
punctuation marks.

- apply `lower()` to it
- do not care about whitespace and punctuation

---

```
word = [c.lower() for c in "No, it can assess an action." if c not in ',. !?']
print(word == word[::-1])  # True as well
```

Comment: Sentence taken from: https://www2.cs.arizona.edu/icon/oddsends/palinsen.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
string = input("Please enter any word: ")
string_length = len(string)
start_index = 0
count = 0 
end_index = string_length - 1
for string_index in range(int(string_length/2)):
    if string[start_index] == string[end_index]:
        start_index = start_index + 1
        end_index = end_index - 1
        count += 1
    else:
        pass
print("Palendrome") if count == int(string_length/2) else print("Not Palendrome")
```

Explanation:
To check for palendrome string compare the first and last character upto the comparison comes to middle of string

```
for string_index in range(int(string_length/2)):
```

compare the first character and last character:

```
if string[start_index] == string[end_index]:
```

Update the start_index and end_index and count:

```
start_index = start_index + 1
end_index = end_index - 1
count += 1
```

If count is equal to half the length of string then it is definitely a Palendrome

```
print("Palendrome") if count == int(string_length/2) else print("Not Palendrome")
```

Comment: Thx for the help, but this is a bit complex xD, it is understandable, but i would prefer mine, but i appreciate the effort from you, many thanks